# How to select a combobox item by value using Winapi message

Tags: winapi, combobox, sendmessage

I have some comboboxes in an application that I need to select from other application.

One of those comboboxes is a combobox that lists years, from 10 years before current year until 10 years in the future.

The problem is if I use CB_SETCURSEL message, it assumes I am selecting by index so of course, it does not select anything.

Select by text is not an option, since among the comboboxes, one that lists months is present. In that case, the value is the month number and the text is the month name.

So the question is: is there a way to send a message to a combobox in order to select the item by value?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Well...how do you add the strings to the combo? By a loop and an array of char*? If so, you can find the index of the desire strings and once have it, send CB_SETCURSEL based on that index.

Comment: I cannot control the way the comboboxes were filled. This is another application developed by someone else. That is why I have asked this, since I should only use the value to send the combobox. Other way it is easy.

Comment: ammm ok, you can get all the strings of the combo, store them in array, search the string in the array, once found it, send the message CB_SETCURSEL...could work?

Comment: I was thinking about that so I am looking for a message to get all combobox items. I think I can use CB_GETITEMDATA in combination with CB_GETCOUNT. Is there a better way?

Comment: Assuming we are in year 2006: for selecting say year 2006 select index 0, for 2007 select index 1 etc. For the months: for january select index 0, for february select index 1 etc. What's wrong with that ?

Comment: @jstuardo the method you mention in your last comment seems OK to me. There is nothing wrong doing this.

Comment: Or use CB_FINDSTRING

Comment: @MichaelWalz The problem is that I cannot know which is the first year, in case of years combobox, so I cannot know how to get the actual index from the year value.

Comment: @jstuardo the first year is the current year (which you know) minus 10.

Comment: @Joel but using CB_FINDSTRIG will search for displayed text, not the value (I could be wrong)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Wrong. I cannot know the first year in combobox. I said 10 years before just to mention an example. The actual application can have the first item as the current year. Other application can have 10 years before. Other application can have 100 years before.

Comment: oh right! Sorry @jstuardo, then I go with loop. My $0.02.

Comment: @jstuardo OK, misunderstood your explanation in the question. As mentioned befire, the loop solution looks OK to me.

Comment: I have tried to use CB_GETITEMDATA  but if returns 0 for all items. Is there a way to get the real value of the item?

Comment: Was the "real" value ever set? By using CB_SETITEMDATA?

Comment: You are making such heavy weather. Read the text of the combo. Use automation.

Comment: A combo only has a data value for its items if the application assigned it, but it's separate from the string value.

Comment: You can't search a ComboBox by "values", because there are no values store in the ComboBox itself (and even if there were, you don't know the type of values the app is storing, it is private data). All you can go on is the displayed strings that the user sees, and `CB_FINDSTRING` works just fine for that.